# What is the correct format of a date string?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, standards

I'm implementing a PDF producer. Among other things, it writes an `/Info` dictionary, containing a `/CreationDate` entry. However, I am confused about the precise format of the date string, in particular whether or not it should have a trailing `'` (apostrophe).

The ISO approved copy [Document Management – Portable Document Format – Part 1: PDF 1.7, First Edition](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) (7.9.4 Dates) prescribes the following format:

> `( D : YYYYMMDDHHmmSSOHH ' mm  )`

In contrast to that, [PDF Reference, Sixth Edition, version 1.7](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf)<sup>1)</sup> (3.8.3 Dates, also published by Adobe) has it documented as:

> `( D : YYYYMMDDHHmmSSOHH ' mm ' )`

(note the trailing apostrophe character)

Which one of these is correct?

---

<sup>1)</sup> *The [Errata to Sixth Edition](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_archives/pdf_17_errata.pdf) does not have an entry for this specific issue.*

Comment: To add to the confusion, the PDF spec you linked has a few examples of date strings with a trailing apostrophe, e.g. at the bottom of page 550.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ISO 32000-1:2008 is the official standard and superseded the Adobe PDF Reference.  Many areas were improved from the 1.7 spec prior to publication by ISO.

In this case, as 32K-1 shows, the extra ' (apostrophe) in the date example is indeed incorrect.  If Adobe's products are writing that extra one at the end, it's a bug and we'll see about fixing it.

I will also point out that for the forthcoming ISO 32000-2 (PDF 2.0), DocInfo is deprecated in favor of XMP.  So if someone is writing a PDF producer in 2016/2017, they shouldn't be worrying about DocInfo but instead focusing on XMP.

Comment: The *date string* specification isn't used just with the DocInfo. There are many places, where a date string can be stored (e.g. collections, annotations, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Well... there's what the PDF Spec **says**, and there's what Adobe Acrobat **does**. When creating a PDF using Adobe Acrobat DC, the trailing apostrophe is present. The good news is, of the viewers I've tested, it doesn't seem to matter either way.

Comment: Viewers are one thing. What about verifiers, though? Are there any, that would flag Acrobat's diversion as non-compliant? I really wish this were less confusing. ISO 32000 says one thing, which references ISO/IEC 8824, which in turn says another thing (it doesn't use any apostrophes), and Adobe decided to violate either one.

Comment: There are a lot of those issues with ISO 32000. Though I haven't seen all of it, ISO 32000-2 (PDF 2.0) seeks to address these issues and remove any deprecated objects and other discrepancies. I believe that'll get published this year if all goes as planned.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on ISO 32000-2, it's much appreciated. I'm sorry for the ranting above, it wasn't meant to address you or your answer. It's just that these things should be simple, and they aren't. Do you happen to have a link to the draft of ISO 32000-2 at hand, if it is available?

Comment: Fear not, I don't take rants personally. I make a living off of PDF and I assure you, it can get frustrating for me as well. 

Here's a pretty good link... https://www.pdfa.org/what-will-pdf-2-0-bring/

Note that the ISO 32000-2 spec will not be free of charge. It's no longer under Adobe control so ISO will be charging for it.